# How to reorder Empathy IM Client Contact List Groups?

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, contacts, ordering, empathy

Does anyone know how to manually rearrange the default contact list groups so they aren't in alphabetical order?

I'm using Empathy 2.30.0.1 Ubuntu 10.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 yesterday and am currently beginning to use Empathy as it is the default Ubuntu IM client now.

In the display menu of the contact list window you can sort your contacts by name or status (online, etc.).

Edit : for group sorting : select a contact in your list, edit it (right-click -> edit or edit menu -> contact -> modify or something like this, my menus are in french). You have a group section in the pop-up window to define new groups or assign a user to existing groups. I did not notice it the first time ! Not so user-friendly...

Although Empathy is new in the Ubuntu default configuration, I really appreciate the support of so many IM protocols and the gnome integration. Personally I would like to sort my contacts by IM protocol and/or groups (edit: found how to !). I'm sure we can now except lot of user feedback in the following months which will boost Empathy development : Ubuntu and Linux users community is still growing !

As it is open source, you are able to contribute to the Empathy development, at least with your user feedback. As I never did that, I cannot explain you how to do it but some nice people are certainly ready to help you !

Cheers :-)

Comment: Thanks for the info but I was trying to reorder the groups themselves, not just contacts within each group. 

I have a few groups that I rarely talk to but keep their screennames cause I have their names saved so if they ever IM me, I know who they are. I guess I could just do character prefixes as a hack...

I'll try looking up the Empathy dev feedback option when I'm a little less busy. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I did not well understood your question and I was talking about an already addressed issue, see: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/540311

Noticed that your group list is stored in the ~/.config/Empathy/contact-groups.xml file but editing the xml group order in the file is not effective because the group list is reordered somewhere else in the source code.

If someone wants to contribute (I can't do it now) : http://live.gnome.org/Empathy/Git.
Maybe start focusing on empathy-main-window.c -> static void)
main_window_view_sort_contacts_cb( etc...

Comment: Thanks Maxime, I guess when I'm free and when it annoys me enough, I'll have to take a crack at it.